# Colorful putty logs?

Tags: putty

Although putty is able to log almost everything being transfered, (i.e. "SSH packets and raw data"), it's unable to create a colorful log.

Is there any way (external tool or hint on how to) to create, say, .rtf log file, in which text would be colored just like in putty window?